# Want to send some Information with message which will be return to server on successfull delivery

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Google GCM service for push notification , it is working properly and receiving request from my server and generating response like below:

```
    {"multicast_id":65162440918454631,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,
"results":[{"message_id":"0:137098281085815%98234feef459fd7ecd"}]}
```

But this is the response of accepting request to Google GCM server not of delivery of Notification to device.

What i want to do is send some **message_id** with request to Google GCM server and when that notification delivered to device it will return that **message_id** ,so that i will update status of respective message_id in database for reporting purpose.

**Code for Request:**

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => array("msg" => $message,"msgid"=>12345),
    "collapse_key" => "message_alert",
    "time_to_live" => 1800,
    "delay_while_idle" => true
);
```

Want a syntax or way by which **message_id** is send to server.

Is there some other way by which delivery status of notification will be get?

Comment: upon delivery you app will have to ping the server and you can record the receipt

Comment: yes it will but there must be some unique message_id which will be send from PHP script to device . how can i will send it?

Comment: bit confused with your last statement

Comment: my app will ping server for delivery of notification but with some unique id of that delivered notification , and that unique id will send from server to device with notification request , i want to know way by which i will send that unique message id with request so that when notification delivered it will return to server via ping.

Comment: add your id to the `payload`

Comment: yes i am trying the same but not have correct syntax for that

Comment: would anyone tell me correct syntax for this purpose

Comment: @Ekansh What's exactly your problem? You included a msgId param in your message (though you should probably send it as "12345"). You should assign its value in your server (and make sure it's unique). Do you have a problem reading that msgId in the application? Do you have a problem sending the acknowledgment back to your server?